# How to resize an image to fit inside a flexbox, and contain everything inside a grid of 1fr?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to create a grid which has 1fr and contains flexboxes and grid inside it . But the `.container` grid decreases in size different than I expected for the smaller screen sizes (used mediaquery).

The flexbox (portfolio-main-card) is used to contain the image and the text with image having `flex:1` and text with `flex:2` respectively . But the image is going way beyond the `flex:1` .The html part for the flexbox is:

```html
<div class="portfolio-main-card">
    <div class="my-image">
        <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fhyperallergic.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F01%2FCat_023-FF.jpg&f=1&nofb=1" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="my-text">
        <div class="my-text-p">
            <p>Welcome to my portfolio</p>
        </div>                
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS part for it is

```css
.portfolio-main-card {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    border:2px solid yellow;
    background-color: rgb(134, 107, 134);
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
   
}

.my-image {
    flex:1 ;
    border: 2px solid red;
    justify-self: center;    
}

.my-text {
    display: flex;
    flex:2;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

The whole code is [here](https://codepen.io/novice_rushed_developer/pen/BaKexow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to style your `<img>` tags

Use the style below and see the result  :)

```
.my-image {
    height:100%;
    width:50%;
    display:flex;
}
.my-image img{
    height:100%;
    object-fit:cover;
    width: 100%;
}
```